# Is there any way to start a setInterval one second after another?

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

http://jsfiddle.net/9DP2d/

```
    setInterval(toggleredBox, 1000);
    setInterval(toggleorangeBox, 1000);
    setInterval(toggleyellowBox, 1000);

var toggleredBox = function toggleredBox() {
    $(".redBox").slideToggle(1000);
};

var toggleorangeBox = function toggleorangeBox() {
    $(".orangeBox").slideToggle(1000);
};

var toggleyellowBox = function toggleyellowBox() {
    $(".yellowBox").slideToggle(1000);
};
```

So the problem is that all 3 boxes are firing all at once: is there any way to get them to go one after another simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do it like this:

```
setInterval(toggleredBox, 3000);

var toggleredBox = function toggleredBox() {
    $(".redBox").slideToggle(1000);
    setTimeout(toggleorangeBox, 1000);
};

var toggleorangeBox = function toggleorangeBox() {
    $(".orangeBox").slideToggle(1000);
    setTimeout(toggleyellowBox, 1000);
};

var toggleyellowBox = function toggleyellowBox() {
    $(".yellowBox").slideToggle(1000);
};
```

Can also have another `setTimeout` in the last function and simply call the function where you want the animation to start.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9DP2d/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout do delay the start:

```
setInterval(toggleredBox, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){
  setInterval(toggleorangeBox, 1000);
}, 1000):
setTimeout(function(){
  setInterval(toggleyellowBox, 1000);
}, 2000):
```

You can also use a single interval for all three, and use a counter to check when to toggle them the first time:

```
setInterval(toggleBoxes, 1000);

var cnt = 0;

function toggleBoxes() {
  $(".redBox").slideToggle(1000);
  if (cnt > 0) $(".orangeBox").slideToggle(1000);
  if (cnt > 1) $(".yellowBox").slideToggle(1000);
  cnt++;
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9DP2d/2/

Answer (score -1):

To try to implement the "one after the other simultaneously" (whatever that means):

```
setInterval(toggleredBox, 1000);

var toggleredBox = function() {
    $(".redBox").slideToggle(1000, toggleorangeBox);
};

var toggleorangeBox = function() {
    $(".orangeBox").slideToggle(1000, toggleyellowBox);
};

var toggleyellowBox = function() {
    $(".yellowBox").slideToggle(1000);
};
```